# SharePoint site authentication with ADFS

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to authenticate SharePoint Web Application(Site) with Adfs, I have added adfs identifier in Central admin for Web application, When I browse Adfs site Login page comes up fine.

But when I try to login site with ADFS users, It redirects me again to Log in Page, I verified Event logs on Server and I found this error : "An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The trusted login provider did not supply a token accepted by this farm.."

Comment: have you use _trust in your url at ADFS side?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added:

1. "**Token Sign-in Certificate**" using *New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer*
2. "Token Sign-in Certificate" as a **Trusted Authority** using *New-SPTrustedRootAuthority*

Please, look at these two resources:

- [Configuring SharePoint 2010 and ADFS v2 End to End](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/configuring-sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-v2-end-to-end/)
- [ADFS 2.0 with Sharepoint 2010 and error accessing site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/33170f0a-87af-4942-8103-198e4ad94148/adfs-20-with-sharepoint-2010-and-error-accessing-site?forum=Geneva)

Comment: Yes, I have added "Token Sign-in Certificate" to New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer and "Token Sign-in Certificate" as a Trusted Authority.  I also gone through both URL which you have mentioned Above, Yes, I configure Claim exactly same. The only difference is I am configuring ADFS 3 on Server 2012